# ImageView Frame Change Condition

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I am building a sample project where I am creating an UIImageView and UIButton programmatically and changing its frame inside a loop. My condition is when I tap my button imagePicker will come and after picking an image from the library and then it will how in the imageView and the button will shift just beside the image view. In this way if I keep on choosing image button will shift every time. I have to keep 3 items in a row, but I have to do this without using collectionView or tableview. For the first row my code is working fine but when I choose image for the third time it is not working as expected. The screenshots will make it more clear.

This is what I want.

[image]

For the first row it is working fine like this

[image]

But when I am tapping the button for the third time and select an image then I am getting like this

[image]

The code for shifting imageView and button is

```
 int x = 8;
 int y = 8;
 int margin = 9;

 for (int i=1;i<=self.arrImages.count;i++){
 if (i%2 == 0 && i%3!=0) {

     [myImage setFrame:CGRectMake(x+margin+95.0, y, 95.0, 95.0)];
     [_addPhotoButton setFrame:CGRectMake((x+margin+95.0)*2, y, 95.0,95.0)];
     x = 8;
     y = y + margin + 95.0;

 }
 else if (i%3 == 0 && i%2 !=0) {
     [myImage setFrame:CGRectMake(x+margin+95.0+95.0+margin, y, 95.0,95.0)];
     [_addPhotoButton setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y+95.0+margin, 95.0, 95.0)];
     x = 8;
     y = y + margin + 95.0;

  }
  else {

      [myImage setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 95.0, 95.0)];
      [_addPhotoButton setFrame:CGRectMake(x+margin+95.0, y, 95.0, 95.0)];

        }

    }

}
```

I am sure that inside for loop, the condition that I have given is wrong. Can anyone please rectify my problem. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int margin = 9;
CGFloat size = 95.0;

UIImage *chosenImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
[self.arrImages addObject:chosenImage];


UIImageView *myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:chosenImage];


myImage.frame = _addPhotoButton.frame;
[self.scrollView addSubview:myImage];

CGFloat x,y;
if(self.arrImages.count %3 == 0) {
    x = 8;
    y = _addPhotoButton.frame.origin.y + _addPhotoButton.frame.size.height + margin;

}
else {
    x = myImage.frame.origin.x + size + margin;
    y = _addPhotoButton.frame.origin.y;
}
_addPhotoButton.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, _addPhotoButton.frame.size.width, _addPhotoButton.frame.size.height);

[self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, _addPhotoButton.frame.size.height + _addPhotoButton.frame.origin.y + 8)];

[self.scrollView layoutIfNeeded];
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Comment: @iPeter - let me know if you need more clarification or help.

Comment: I promise! I stuck in this problem the last 3 days. @DanielS

Comment: You understood my problem a little bit wrong. My button is shifting every time after choosing images.

Comment: I assumed that the code you wrote is performed each time after adding an image (choosing image with picker). You should then position all images and then position button (this is what my code does). If I misunterstood you please provide some more explanations (maybe attach more code)

Comment: Okay. Lemme explain in more brief. At first, when you run the project, the button is shown at first. You tap on it picker comes. You choose an image. Then after dismissing the picker the chosen image will come to the imageview. Now, the imageview's position is where the button was at first and now the button's position is just beside the image view with margin gap. Now in this way, every time you choose images the images will show one beside another and button also gets shifted every time with the imageviews. Now have you understood what I exactly need? @DanielS

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I understand at first time. From your code it looks like you are repositioning all images (I assume that _arrImages_ contains all images that were picked - including the one picked recently) and position it. If it's not true add clarification what is the content of _arrImages_ and when the code you've attached is preformed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75188/discussion-between-ipeter-and-daniels).